# Shared Hosting session passing on multiple devices

Tags: php, session, server

Last few I faced a new type of problem that my session also cookie show the same on both my PC and laptop. Sometimes its also passing another device too. On google search, I found few articles that it unfortunately happened for some case in shared hosting.

My server tmp file didn't make any new session for new device, So on .htaccess i put `php_value session.save_path '/home/domain/newtmp/'`  and its now create a new file for any new device and remove after a certain time by cronjob.

I tried to create a session token and Cookie to identify a device, but `print_r($_SESSION); print_r($_COOKIE);`  on both device showed same info as which device first open on the browser.

I also test `$_SESSION['user_agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`, here `echo $_SESSION['user_agent']` showed first opened device`s browser info in 2nd device browser window. After 40/50 secound, if I refreshed the browser its came back by own info.

But a separate session file by session token has already show on the server tmp file.

After removed my all file I just use `session_start(); $_SESSION['pass'] = rand(100, 999); echo $_SESSION['pass'];` in my 4 web hosting server(there all shared hosting from same company). This code showing same in 2 hosting server and another 2 server working well.

I never faced this type of session experience before.

How to get rid of this problem. I cannot afford dedicated hosting so I want to solve this problem anymore if you are all help me.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long analysis and google search, I got this problem name is "session data crossover". This is very rear cash for any shared hosting server. I also tested my script in many shared hosting and at last found only my current hosting server did this type of behavior. So all problem is solved after shifting my hosting server.